# Upgrading dojo in Spring-js from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-js

We have a project where we're using `Spring-js`. With it comes `Spring-dojo` and the full `dojo` package. But in the current version of `Spring-js (2.0.9)`, it's using `dojo 1.3`. Is there a way to upgrade manually to `dojo 1.4`? Or even a new `Spring-js.jar`-file that can be donwloaded that uses `dojo 1.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If you are using the ResourceServlet, you can simply drop the new version of Dojo in the top-level directory of your WAR structure.  The ResourceServlet always looks there before it looks on the classpath, thus resources in top-level of the WAR take precedence.  I would suggest using a full uncompressed source distro of Dojo during development, and then doing a custom build that is tailored to your usage patterns for production.

Beware that we've occasionally seen some minor incompatibilities when upgrading Dojo versions, so be on the lookout for that and report any issues in the Web Flow Jira.

I suspect we'll be upgrading to Dojo 1.4 in the official distribution for the upcoming Spring Web Flow 2.1 release.

Comment: Any release date set for WebFlow 2.1?

Comment: I don't think there's a set date yet, but M1 was just released recently, and the complete dev cycle shouldn't be all that long since it's mainly just about first-class support for Spring 3.0, rather than a big-feature release as Web Flow 3.0 (which is also in progress) will be.

Comment: Now that 2.1 is released, it doesn't seem like dojo 1.4 was included? Since you said "we'll be upgrading", I'm guessing you're on the team, and maybe have some more information about this? Is it pushed out to Spring-WebFlow 2.1.1, or to Spring-WebFlow 3? I see that Spring-JS is no longer its own project on your jira, either?

Answer (score 0):

Btw., spring webflow 2.0.9 uses dojo 1.2.4 not 1.3 as the release notes tell